# MEF - Access Violation on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, mef, azure-worker-roles

I'm using the MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework) in a Azure web role and when I try to execute the operation I have a dump.

I can't find a reason since this doesn't happen in the local emulator, only happens on Azure.

how can I find what's causing this Access Violation?

```
ModLoad: 00000000`20be0000 00000000`20bf6000   Components.SAFT.PT.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`20bc0000 00000000`20bd6000   E:\APPROOT\PLUGINS\RELEASE\COMPONENTS.SAFT.PT.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`1fc30000 00000000`1fc38000   Platform.Integration.Gateway.Interfaces.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`20940000 00000000`20948000   Platform.Integration.Gateway.Interfaces.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`1fc30000 00000000`1fc38000   E:\approot\Platform.Integration.Gateway.Interfaces.dll
1 component(s) are imported successfully.
ModLoad: 000007fa`0b730000 000007fa`0badf000   D:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Web.28b9ef5a#\a26ae05e40d4b4d572ea96702ea749bd\System.Web.Extensions.ni.dll
CLR:(D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll) Rejecting native image because dependency D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll is not native
ModLoad: 00000000`20120000 00000000`202e4000   System.Web.Extensions.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`2b9f0000 00000000`2bbb4000   System.Web.Extensions.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`20120000 00000000`202e4000   D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll
(8a0.8f0): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
000007f9`c88f2a52 488b00          mov     rax,qword ptr [rax] ds:00000000`00000000=????????????????
```

Code:

```
var t = new Platform.Integration.Components.SAFTBuilderImporter();
t.DoImport();
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} component(s) are imported successfully.", t.AvailableNumberOfBuilders));
var result = t.CallAllComponents(
startDate,
endDate);
```

Comment: is your dev machine running 32bit OS?

Comment: The DEV machine is 64x. The error is happening on Azure production environment.